# RobotFramework: SHIFT+ENTER Combination Press Keys SeleniumLibrary

Tags: selenium, robotframework, selenium2library

There is a button on the Webpage that gets pressed when I do SHIFT ENTER (I cannot use `Click Element`, as this is a Keyboard function keys test). But the `Press Keys` from the `SeleniumLibrary (3.3.0)`, seems not working, i mean the button is not getting pressed. I tried following combination keys nothing seem to work.

```
    Press Keys    ${None}   SHIFT+ENTER
    Press Keys    ${None}   SHIFT+RETURN
    Press Keys    ${None}   SHIFT    ENTER
```

Here is the log trace

```
KEYWORD Selenium2Library . Press Keys ${None}, SHIFT+ENTER
Documentation:  
Simulates user pressing key(s) to an element or on the active browser.

Start / End / Elapsed:  20210424 09:07:57.794 / 20210424 09:07:57.846 / 00:00:00.052
09:07:57.794    TRACE   Arguments: [ None | 'SHIFT+ENTER' ] 
09:07:57.795    INFO    Sending key(s) (u'SHIFT+ENTER',) to page.   
09:07:57.795    INFO    Pressing special key SHIFT down.    
09:07:57.796    INFO    Pressing special key ENTER down.    
09:07:57.796    INFO    Releasing special key SHIFT.    
09:07:57.796    INFO    Releasing special key ENTER.    
09:07:57.796    DEBUG   POST http://127.0.0.1:56002/session/7fee5882a08a0a823f6619b52bb6ae7c/actions {"actions": [{"parameters": {"pointerType": "mouse"}, "type": "pointer", "id": "mouse", "actions": [{"duration": 0, "type": "pause"}, {"duration": 0, "type": "pause"}, {"duration": 0, "type": "pause"}, {"duration": 0, "type": "pause"}]}, {"type": "key", "id": "key", "actions": [{"type": "keyDown", "value": "\ue008"}, {"type": "keyDown", "value": "\ue007"}, {"type": "keyUp", "value": "\ue008"}, {"type": "keyUp", "value": "\ue007"}]}]}  
09:07:57.846    DEBUG   http://127.0.0.1:56002 "POST /session/7fee5882a08a0a823f6619b52bb6ae7c/actions HTTP/1.1" 200 14 
09:07:57.846    DEBUG   Finished Request    
09:07:57.846    TRACE   Return: None
```

I think the problem is with the Sequence. when i tried the same sequence manually, it didn't work

```
09:07:57.795    INFO    Pressing special key SHIFT down.    
09:07:57.796    INFO    Pressing special key ENTER down.    
09:07:57.796    INFO    Releasing special key SHIFT.    
09:07:57.796    INFO    Releasing special key ENTER.
```

It should've been like this and this way it works manually

```
09:07:57.795    INFO    Pressing special key SHIFT down.    
09:07:57.796    INFO    Pressing special key ENTER down.    
09:07:57.796    INFO    Releasing special key ENTER.
09:07:57.796    INFO    Releasing special key SHIFT.
```

Any idea how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 1):

Try targeting the body tag instead of None

```
Press Keys    xpath://body   SHIFT+ENTER
Press Keys    xpath://body   SHIFT+RETURN
```

If it still fails you will have to use some other library such as [AutoIt](https://pypi.org/project/robotframework-autoitlibrary/) or [PyAutoGUI](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).